# pushstate is not working correctly in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, html, url, backbone.js, pushstate

If I am using Backbone with pushstate, how should I format my links?

Currently I am doing this:

```
<a href="task/create">create task</a>
```

If I use the above format, it actually sends a `GET` request to the server, which serves a standard page and backbone correctly identifies that it should go to `task/create`, which it does, and shows the view.

But why is it sending a `GET` request in the first place? (even though I have set pushstate to true?)

edit: I am using the latest version of Chrome (as of August 2011), so my browser is not a problem, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok got it answered from here. https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/456

clicking links are not suppose to be pushstate friendly. one may try to live bind it via jquery and use custom function to create that effect.

Comment: Even if you were only using 'hashchange', it's probably not a good idea to rely on links in order to future-proof your app.

Comment: Actually, future-proofing is exactly what you would be doing by using links.  If your backbone routes match your application routes, then the links will work even if JavaScript is turned off, or if you are crawled by a search engine.

Answer (score 0):

In case any other readers would like more information on routing, there's a whole chapter dedicated to explaining routing available in pages 32-46 here: http://samples.leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction-sample.pdf (full disclosure: I'm the book author)